# Typeably casting GADTs

Tags: haskell, existential-type, gadt

Let's say I'm writing a DSL and want to have support for both phantom type support and badly typed expressions. My value types might be

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs, DataKinds #-}

data Ty = Num | Bool deriving (Typeable)

data Val a where
  VNum  :: Int  -> Val Num
  VBool :: Bool -> Val Bool
```

and I can work with an phantom erased version

```
{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification #-}

data Valunk = forall a . Valunk (V' a)
```

Now, I can operate on values of `Valunk` by `case`ing out both `VNum` and `VBool` and even reestablish my phantom types in this way

```
getNum :: Valunk -> Maybe (Val Num)
getNum (Valunk n@(VNum _)) = Just n
getNum _                   = Nothing
```

But this just feels like I'm reimplementing the `Typeable` machinery. Unfortunately, GHC won't let me derive a `Typeable` for `Val`

```
src/Types/Core.hs:97:13:
    Can't make a derived instance of `Typeable (Val a)':
      Val must only have arguments of kind `*'
    In the data declaration for Val
```

Is there a way to get around this restriction? I'd love to write

```
getIt :: Typeable a => Valunk -> Maybe (Val a)
getIt (Valunk v) = cast v
```

but right now I have to resort to machinery like this

```
class Typeably b x where kast :: x a -> Maybe (x b)
instance Typeably Num Val where 
  kast n@(VNum _) = Just n
  kast _          = Nothing
```

for all of my types.

Comment: It looks like the `deriving (Typeable)` machinery has not yet been made to work with `DataKinds`. `DataKinds` doesn't give you anything amazing, just a little extra checking.    You can use `data Num` and `data Bool` instead of your `Ty` kind.

Answer (score 1):

You can derive Data.Typeable on your own:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs, DataKinds, DeriveDataTypeable, ExistentialQuantification #-}

import Data.Typeable

data Ty = TNum | TBool deriving Typeable 

data Valunk = forall a. Typeable a => Valunk a 

data Val a where 
    VInt :: Int -> Val TNum
    VBool :: Bool -> Val TBool 

instance Show (Val a) where 
    show (VInt a) = show a
    show (VBool a) = show a 

valtypenam = mkTyCon3 "package" "module" "Val"

instance Typeable (Val a) where 
    typeOf _ = mkTyConApp valtypenam []

getIt :: Valunk -> Maybe (Val a)
getIt (Valunk p) = cast p
```

This will provide the get it function. Just be sure to name your type correctly (thus file the package, module and type truthfully) otherwise other packages can get into problems.

For some more examples of how to write these instances, look into: [Data.Derive.Typeable source](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/derive/2.5.5/doc/html/src/Data-Derive-Typeable.html).

**EDIT:**  I had a very strange copy and past error in the code, but now it works.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to store a witness that the quantified type in `Valunk` is in `Typeable`:

```
data Valunk = forall a . Typeable a => Valunk (Val a)
```

Once you have this, you can just use `gcast` to achieve what you're asking for:

```
getIt :: Typeable a => Valunk -> Maybe (Val a)
getIt (Valunk v) = gcast v
```

This was tested with:

```
data Val a where
  VNum  :: Int  -> Val Int
  VBool :: Bool -> Val Bool
```